# MVC4 jQuery Page navigation State

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a existing MVC4 project where we use to switch between screens using jQuery AJAX html() function. Ideally, the URL needs to be changed on every action so that the user can use the Back button (browser) to go back, but we are not changing the URL.

Ex:
`http://mywebsite/bank/verify` - link used to show login screen, lists the accounts and then their transactions step by step. When the user refreshes the page, the actions starts from login again which I want to avoid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery Mobile? They've implemented a slick navigation mechanism using hashtags that I think is what you are after. Don't let the name fool you JQM can certainly be used in desktop scenarios.

Comment: I haven't. I will take a look now. Thank you very much @ChrisHardie